# Inhomogeneous Brusselator model

Tags: differential-equations, complex-systems, bifurcation

I am studying a Brusselator model which includes inhomogeneous terms such as $\nabla ^2 x$ and $\nabla^2 y$ in the following way

\begin{aligned}
&\partial_{\tau} x=a-(b+1) x+x^{2} y+d_{X} \nabla^{2} x, \\
&\partial_{\tau} y=b x-x^{2} y+d_{Y} \nabla^{2} y,
\end{aligned}

where $a, d_X, d_Y$ and $b$ are constant parameters.

I am asked to study the linear stability of the steady homogeneous state (which I think is $x_{\mathrm{sth}} = a, y_{\mathrm{sth}} = b/a$) and show that if

$\eta \equiv \sqrt{d_{x} / d_{y}} >\left(\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-1\right)/a$

then a Hopf bifurcation occurs when changing the value of $b$. I am not asking for the solution of this last statement, I am just very confused because if the regime is the homogeneus stationary state, the factors $d_X$ and $d_Y$ shouldn't play any role, right?

In terms of the Jacobian matrix $J$, I obtain: trace($J$) = $b-1-a^2$ and det($J$) = $a^2$, so $d_X$ and $d_Y$ don't appear.

Comment: This [paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/S021812741250037X) might be helpful (while they don't comment on the intuition, they show the explicit derivation you need, which might be enlightening). The paper is not open access, but I could get it searching in Google Scholar (or, more precisely, using the browser add-on "Google Scholar Button").

Comment: Thank you very much @stafusa, at least now I know where the terms come from. I'll keep working on the intuition!